# Unable to install Kerberos libriaries using $ rpm -ivf krb5-libs-1.8.4-3.fc14.x86_64.rpm

Tags: linux, yum, kerberos, rpm

My Linux version is as follows:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)
My rpm version is 4.4.2.3

when I am trying ti run uname -a ,the output i sas follows:

```
Linux ca1vmprdpsoft1.kla-tencor.com 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 21:52:39 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have downloaded `krb5-libs-1.8.4-3.fc14.x86_64.rpm` from http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=krb5-libs .

```
$ rpm -ivf krb5-libs-1.8.4-3.fc14.x86_64.rpm
warning: krb5-libs-1.8.4-3.fc14.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA signature: NOKEY, key                                                                                                  ID 42d68235
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) is needed by krb5-libs-1.8.4-3.fc14.x86_64
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by krb5-libs-1.8.4-3.fc14.x86_6                                                                                                 4
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by krb5-libs-1.8.4-3.fc14.x86_64
```

Please let me know which version of Keberos library should I download so that this error would be resolved or any other suggestion to resolve this issues.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, RPM Dependency management.. Or lack of.

You'd be better to configure `yum` to look at EPEL repositories, then use `yum` to install what you want, rather than using `rpm`.

Also, it looks like that version of krb5 requires a more recent version of glibc than you've got.  This kinda upgrade tends to happen when you're looking at a version of a package that's a lot more recent than the current version for your RHEL build.

You're also trying to install packages from Fedora Core 14 onto a RHEL 5.5 system.
**Are there not any vendor supported kerberos libraries?**  I mean, you're paying a shitload for support, you might as well use it.

Good luck getting it working without breaking the existing system.

But yeah.. You should be using yum, really.

Comment: So, I don't have a 5.5 box to pull this up on, but the current version for the 5 series is krb5-libs-1.6.1-62.el5. It is available in the base rhel-${arch}-(server|workstation)-5 channel.